# Calculate angle of the roll using acceleration sensor

Tags: java, android, math, physics, android-sensors

At android programming(Java+android studio)

How can I calculate the angle of the roll using acceleration sensor?
i have angle of Pitch & Yaw.

We have mobile acceleration in three directions. X, y, z And we want the angle and degree of rotation of the roll

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if(event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){

        float xVal = event.values[0];
        float yVal = event.values[1];
        float zVal = event.values[2];

        sx = "X Value : <font color = '#800080'> " + xVal + "</font>";
        sy = "Y Value : <font color = '#800080'> " + yVal + "</font>";
        sz = "Z Value : <font color = '#800080'> " + zVal + "</font>";

        x.setText(Html.fromHtml(sx));
        y.setText(Html.fromHtml(sy));
        z.setText(Html.fromHtml(sz));

        double angle = Math.atan2(zVal, xVal)/(Math.PI/180);

        ang.setText(String.valueOf(angle));


    }
```

Math.atan2(؟و؟)/(Math.PI/180);?! or other solveway .

I dont know english goodly.
thanks.

Comment: You need to give much more context to avoid being too broad. Show your code which reads the input and outputs at least the integrated/accumulated values in a loop.

Comment: It is clear.
We have mobile acceleration in three directions. X, y, z
And we want the angle and degree of rotation of the roll

Comment: Add that useful information to the question itself (by using [edit]) and show some code context, please.

Comment: Please review your edit, you have undone an improvement by some other caring soul.

Comment: What is wrong with your current approach?

Comment: no. answer for pitch & Yaw angle is:
double angle = Math.atan2(zVal, yVal)/(Math.PI/180) //for pitch
double angle = Math.atan2(xVal, yVal)/(Math.PI/180) //for Yaw
they are tested. but for roll not response.

Comment: You cannot compute the roll if you only know a single direction, because a direction vector constrains only two degrees of freedom.

Comment: But We have mobile acceleration in three directions. X, y, z

Comment: Yes you have a vector composed of three coordinates, but this consists of a direction - which gives the pitch and yaw (2 degrees of freedom), and a magnitude - the length of the vector (1 degree). There is no roll information.

Comment: Ok and thanks ; So how do you calculate the mobile roll angle?

Comment: use the gyroscope

Comment: But how do I do it?